# How to apply min-height to DIV using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I want to apply min-height to `".wide-content"`

`min-height` of .wide-content = height of right content - "274px"

```
var leftHeight = $(".wide.content").height();
var rightHeight = $("#right_column").height();
alert (leftHeight); alert (rightHeight);

if (leftHeight < rightHeight) {
  $(".wide.content").css('minHeight' 'leftHeight - 274');
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a string for the assigned value, you need the actual number, like this:

```
if (leftHeight < rightHeight) {
  $(".wide.content").css('minHeight', leftHeight - 274);
}
```

Also when using [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), instead of `.css('prop' 'value')` you need a comma in there, like this:

```
$(selector).css('prop', 'value');
//or:
$(selector).css({'prop': 'value'}); //when assigning many at once, like this:
$(selector).css({'prop': 'value', 'prop2': 'value2'});
```

Answer (score 2):

The following piece of code works for me.

```
   $('#test').css({
      minHeight: 500
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery follows `camelCase` naming convention as well `-` separated css property naming convention.

Exampl:

```
CSS             JQuery
=========       =======
font-size       fontSize or font-size
border-width    borderWidth or border-width
```

Comment: This isn't accurate, jQuery lets you specify *either*, it'll convert a capital letter into `-lowercase`, e.g. `C` becomes `-c` in the string, it's a very simple regex conversion.  That being said, he's following that convention, `minHeight` == `min-height` already.